# How to install intel driver in Lubuntu

Tags: linux, drivers

I've recently installed Lubuntu on my PC. But I don't know how to install my Intel chipset driver (intel_inf8111010fin.exe).

Specs: Lubuntu 13.10 (Salamander) & WinXp Sp3 P4 cpu 2.60, 1 ram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That chipset driver is for Windows only. You don't really need to install anything for Lubuntu to work properly with Intel Hardware.

Comment: So how do i install video driver? My pc is kinda old (hp a347x) and its dont have display card on onboard.

Comment: Lubuntu has Intel Video card drivers built in.

Comment: But in lubuntu my graphics drivers are unrecognized.

Comment: What do you mean unrecognised ? You don't get any video at all ?

Comment: My screen messed up like no graphic computer. Colors, wallapers looks so awfull. In winxp i installed that driver and everythings works fine.
EDIT: I will upload screenshot when i get home.